# Why is the lock on the key not held?

Tags: sql-server, locking

When analyzing a locking error in SQL Server I found a design decision which causes deadlocks.
I want to understand why this decision was made. As for context: If somebody updates a table I have a trigger that writes the username in the table. That is why in session 1 there is a second update in the same transaction.

Below I describe how you can provoke the deadlock and show the locks held by the processes. Then I will detail the question.

First, open three sessions in SQL Server and copy the below code in.

---

```
--Session 1

create table ##tTestTable
    (ID int
    , Wert varchar(max)
    , [User] varchar(max) null)

Select *
From ##tTestTable

insert into ##tTestTable
Select 1, 'A', null

insert into ##tTestTable
Select 2, 'A', null

create index TestIndex on ##tTestTable (ID)

Begin transaction

Select @@SPID as FirstTransactionProcessID

Update ##tTestTable --with (holdlock)
Set Wert = 'B'
where ID in (1)

--Stop here and start session 2

Update ##tTestTable
set [User] = SYSTEM_USER
where ID in (1)

commit
```

---

```
--Session 2

Begin transaction

Select @@SPID as FirstTransactionProcessID

Update ##tTestTable
Set Wert = 'C'
where ID in (1)

commit
```

---

```
--Session 3
exec sp_lock
```

---

Now execute everything in session one up to the comment that says "stop". Then execute session 2 and have a look at the locks with session 3.

Mine looks like this:
[image: Locks]

Process 64 is session 1 and 69 is session 2.

As you can see session 1 holds an X lock on row 7:184:0. Session 2 would like to have a U lock on that row but since U and X are incompatible it has to wait. However, session 2 holds a U lock on the key. Now if you execute the second part of session 1 it would also like to have a u lock on the key. Session 1 waits for session 2 and vice versa. The SQL server detects the deadlock and kills session 2.

I changed the ID in session 2 to 2 to check whether the key is one big thing or divided by ID. When doing the test no deadlock occured.

My takeaway: The keylock and the rowlock lock are the exact same row. But when the first update of session 1 resolves it lifts the U lock off the key and keeps an X lock on the row.

Wouldn't it always be better for session 1 to keep the U lock on the key to avoid this deadlock situation? Does somebody have one good example why it makes sense to lift the U lock?

Comment: 2 things to try; your table is a heap (make it clustered); add much more data to the table (so there is more than 1 page)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat is this a test that will help me answer the questions myself?

Comment: You are correct that it does take the `U` lock on the key and then release that, If you use an explicit `UPDLOCK` hint then the key lock is retained. I presume it is released as the update doesn't lead to an update on the index key row itself.

Comment: `Wouldn't it always be better` no. More and wider locks mean more conflicts, more blocking and more chances for deadlocks, especially in high-traffic databases. The longer a transaction takes to complete, the higher the chances for conflicts and deadlocks. The problem here is the two UPDATEs, when a single one would be enough. UPDATE is atomic so a single UPDATE wouldn't need an explicit transaction

Comment: You *can* [raise the isolation level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) above the default `READ COMMITTED` to `REPEATABLE READ` or even `SERIALIZABLE` but that would increase blocking and reduce performance.

Comment: This is a good question actually. It knows up front that the update to the `Wert` column is never going to cause an update of the index itself and require an `X` lock on the index key row as that column is not contained in it. So not sure why it is even bothering with `U` locks here if it doesn't retain them on rows that qualify and will always release them.

Comment: I guess the real question is why your index isn't clustered. Then you don't have a bookmark lookup (a typical cause of a deadlock).

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want your `CLUSTERED` on `ID` (for some reason) then `INCLUDE` the other columns (`User` and `Wert`) in your index `TestIndex`. That also avoids the deadlock